# PostgreSQL Function to Add records with optional parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert, sql-function

I would like to know if what I do is the correct method to add records to a table with optional parameters, in particular I would like to know how i can improve the code inside the " IF ".

I'm using postgreSQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_record(_ID_Father_table VARCHAR(10), _ID_Son_table VARCHAR(10), _Optional1 VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT ' ', _Optional2 INTEGER DEFAULT -1) 
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Father_Table(ID_Father) VALUES (_ID_Father_Table);
    INSERT INTO Son_Table(ID_Son, ID_Father) VALUES (_ID_Son_Table, _ID_Father_Table);

    IF _Optional1 <> ' ' THEN 
        UPDATE Son_Table SET Optional1 =_Optional1  WHERE ID_Son=_ID_Son; 
    END IF;

    IF _Optional2 <> -1 THEN 
        UPDATE Paese SET Optional2=_Optional2 WHERE ID_Son=_ID_Son; 
    END IF;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The Father_Table can be (for example) Son_Table, Son_Table2 and Son_Table3 
with a total and exclusive isa hierarchy.

```
Father_Table(ID_Father, ...)
    PK: ID_Father

Son_Table(ID_Son, ID_Father, Optional1, Optional2)
    PK: ID_Son, ID_Father
    FK: ID_Father References Father_Table

Son_Table2(ID_Son2, ID_Father, ...)
    PK: ID_Son, ID_Father
    FK: ID_Father References Father_Table
```

Comment: Does it work for you? Have you tested it? Or are you asking something more along the lines of whether what you have done is a "best practice" or not?

Comment: It works, but for me isn't correct use multiple if with multiple update, there is a "best practice" to do this?
Besides being a total and exclusive hierarchy i would to know if it is right to add the record to the parent table and then to his son , carrying the key to the father to the son (line 4-5) .